# Is a "normal" python object automatically a tensor? e.g. "a" or 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm struggling to understand why this function works:

```
def tf_load_data(training, batch_size, img_path_list, label_list):

    # Arguments:
    # path_to_image: a Tensor of type string
    # returns 3-D float Tensor of shape [new_height, new_width, channels]
    def get_img(path_to_img):
        # load the raw data, encoded as string.
        raw_img = tf.io.read_file(path_to_img)
        # Creates a 3D uint8 tensor.
        img = ts.io.decode_png(raw_img, channels=3)  # pictures are not saved as Grayscale
        # Changes the values in the tensor to be floats in [0,1). -- Normalization
        img = ts.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
        # Resize all pictures to the same format.
        return ts.image.resize(img, [constant.IMG_WIDTH, constant.IMG_HEIGHT])

    # Arguments:
    # label_string: as byte:32 which represents a string
    # path_to_image: as byte:32 which represents a string
    # returns a pair of two Tensors
    def get_pair(path_to_img, label_string):
        return get_img(path_to_img), lable_string

    # Arguments: -- function is use together with tf.data.Dataset.map or tf.data.Dataset.apply
    # img: is a Tensor of type String
    # label: is a Tensor of type String
    # return: the type is the same as input
    def pre_process(img, label):
        # Do all the pre-processing:
        return img, label

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((img_path_list, label_list))
    dataset_tensor = dataset.map(map_func=get_pair, num_parallel_calls=None)
```

img_path_list and label_list are lists of type string.

The thing that I don't get is that apparently 
`dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((img_path_list, label_list))`
is a Tensor containing tuples (). So when I run the `.map(map_func=get_pair, num_parallel_calls=None)` two strings are passed, as a tuple, in the `get_pair(path_to_img, label_string):` function. One these strings is then passed in the `get_img(path_to_img)` function and finally to `tf.io.read_file(path_to_img)`.
The problem is that `io.read_file()` needs an input: "Tensor of type string" (see docs : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/read_file). 
But string != to Tensor of type string:

```
isinstance(tf.constant["hello"], tf.Tensor) == True
```

`isinstance("hello", tf.Tensor) == False` as well as: `isinstance(["hello"], tf.Tensor) == False`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are explicitly using ``tf`` (tensorflow) calls, why do you wonder that you get tensors? In your ``isinstance`` tests, you aren't using any ``tf`` calls, why do you wonder these aren't ``tf`` tensors?

Comment: Either way, ``tf`` is an external package and Python itself has absolutely no knowledge about what it is. No builtin type is ever a tensor. However, ``tf`` may choose to promote arbitrary objects to tensors, if it knows how to.

Comment: Ok i see, maybe it just converted it for me.